# Asserting an Imported Function is Called (Python)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, matplotlib, mocking, assert

I have to write some tests to assert certain functions are called, such as the `plot` function from `matplotlib.pyplot`. Here's the code I have so far:

```
def test_plot_call(self):
    with patch("matplotlib.pyplot.plot") as plot_call:
        import attempt
        plot_call.assert_has_calls([call(attempt.X,attempt.Y1)])
```

This is to test that `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` has been called in a certain way from a module called `attempt`.

This works fine if the function is called as `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(X,Y1)`, but I need it to also work when the `attempt` module has called `plot` like this:

```
from pylab import *
X = # somethin
Y1 = # somethin

plot(X,Y1)
```

Under these circumstances, `test_plot_call` will fail - but I want it to pass.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you think you need to do this / what is the bigger issue you are trying to solve with this test?

Comment: If you are sure this approach is the way to go, can't you monkey patch both, `pylab` and `pyplot`? (I'm assuming this is what your `patch` function is doing. Just modify it to take multiple functions/modules, or nest two `with`s and check either of them.)

Comment: Btw, I think the test will fail if `X` or `Y1` are reassigned in `attempt` after the call to plot. Is this intended?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already? If you did not get any satisfying answer the solution is not to repost it, but to think about why nobody answered it and clearify it, such that it can be answered.

Comment: @kazemakase I'm writing tests for a system which automatically gives feedback for students at university. I need to find a way to test that they use the plot function, and it needs to pass when they use it this way because they are taught to do it this way

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have no idea how to make the question clearer - I'm just looking for help, but it seems like this is somehow an impossible problem to solve

Comment: @CoffeeDonut I suspected something like that :) This is problably not the right place for discussion, but I can't resist...  With a test like that you basically force the students to do it *exactly* like they were taught. They even have to use the same variable names. (But they are allowed to do `from pylab import *`? This is horrible!) Have you considered just saving the figures to compare the result against a reference image?

Comment: It would already help to see a [mcve], which defines all used variables, such that the code can be run. Adding to the discussion, it seems indeed rather strange to force students to use the `plot` function, while there a other valid ways to produce a line, e.g. a `LineCollection`, but at the same time give them the freedom to use pylab, which is deprecated for a couple of years now. In any case, adding the motivation of what exactly should be tested here *in the question* would also help people understanding the issue.

Comment: Thinking about it, the problem itself is also pretty much independent on matplotlib. So if you create a [mcve] containing a module, which can be imported in two different ways instead of using matplotlib here, and then ask your question using the python tag, you may get a lot more attention to your question.

Comment: @kazemakase this is not a python course, it's a first year science course with a small programming component - all I need is a way to ensure they call the plot function. I have no control over the content of the course either, and this is the way that the students will need it. I don't want to over complicate things - all I wanted was a way to assert that the plot function is called. I've given up now though, obviously it's more complex than I thought

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm a casual tutor to a first year science course, and I haven't even gone into my third year of study yet - I don't want to over complicate things, I just wanted a simple way to assert the plot() call. I still honestly don't see how to make the question any simpler, so I think I'll just skip all the tests and assume the students call the right functions. Thanks for your advice though - admittedly, most of it went over my head.